# Cookies not expiring on all pages

Tags: php, logging, cookies

I'm working on a little log in syetms for my website, hwoever have hit a little snag. I'm using cookies to track which users are logged in. I'm trying to make some pages restricted to vistors that have logged in only, so I decided to use `if($_COOKIE["loggedIn"] == TRUE){` This works for the log in page but when I logout using  `setcookie("loggedIn", NULL, time() - 60000);` All the other pages apart from the log in page retain the value TRUE, the username value also remains set on teh other pages but no the log in page. I originally set the cookie `setcookie("loggedIn", TRUE, time() + 3600);`. I'm still very new to php so any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For logging in and consistency between pages. It might be better to put `session_start()` at the top of all your pages and use `$_SESSION` instead of `$_COOKIE`.